# C# + Excel - How do I fix "Value not within expected range" error in a call to Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat()?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to print each sheet in the Excel Workbook as a separate PDF. But I keep getting a `System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'` at the line `w.ExportAsFixedFormat(...);`

What would be the right syntax to achieve this?

**Code I used:**

```
foreach (Worksheet w in ws.Worksheets)
{
     var wname = Path.Combine(
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
         "Export\\" + w.Name + ".pdf"
     );

     w.ExportAsFixedFormat(
         XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
         wname,
         XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard,
         true,
         false,
         1,
         w.PageSetup.Pages.Count,
         false,
         false
     );
}
```

**Update:**
I should mention that I'm using this with Office 2013, Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Value does not fall within the expected range." error while exporting excel to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061690/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-error-while-exporting-excel-to)

Comment: Not a duplicate I believe. The other post refers to office 2007 where Export-to-PDF is a plugin, whereas in Office 2013, the feature is built-in.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I realised afterwards but you'd closed the question so couldn't remove the flag.

Comment: Yeah, I was too hasty there. Apologies for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs of the method your issue might be the last parameter. 
[Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb238907(v=office.12))

Try:

```
foreach (Worksheet w in ws.Worksheets)
{
     var wname = Path.Combine(
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
         "Export\\" + w.Name + ".pdf"
     );

     w.ExportAsFixedFormat(
         XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
         wname,
         XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard,
         true,
         false,
         1,
         w.PageSetup.Pages.Count,
         false
     );
}
```

(Removed last parameter from method call)
Let me know if that works :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!